# Search for string with anything in in it in Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

I want to search any string with a random number of characters in it in the search field of Visual Studio Code.
I tried `'[a-z]'` but that's not working.

Comment: *I want to search any string with a random number of characters in it* - why?

Comment: to see where there are untranslated strings

Comment: what is the difference to a translated string and untranslated, that is what you need to specify in the regex